# Mutating the user object,that is stored in the database in next auth after registration

Tags: javascript, next.js, updating, next-auth

I have a nextjs application which uses next auth for authentication,I used a database strategy,
After a user login is there still a way to update a user's data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone some azroos this issue,in the nextjs docs there is a user model,so you just have to create a user model in your application and create a usual PUT/PATXH request ****

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).